# JQ get objects from array that has a field ending in string

Tags: arrays, object, jq

I am trying to do what I think should be a fairly simple filter but I keep running into errors. I have this JSON:

```json
{
  "versions": [
    {
      "archived": true,
      "description": "Cod version 3.3/Sprint 8",
      "id": "11500",
      "name": "v 3.3",
      "projectId": 11500,
      "releaseDate": "2016-03-15",
      "released": true,
      "self": "https://xxxxxxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/version/11500",
      "startDate": "2016-02-17",
      "userReleaseDate": "14/Mar/16",
      "userStartDate": "16/Feb/16"
    },
    {
      "archived": true,
      "description": "Hot fix",
      "id": "12000",
      "name": "v3.3.1",
      "projectId": 11500,
      "releaseDate": "2016-03-15",
      "released": true,
      "self": "https://xxxxxxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/version/12000",
      "startDate": "2016-03-15",
      "userReleaseDate": "14/Mar/16",
      "userStartDate": "14/Mar/16"
    },
    {
      "archived": false,
      "id": "29704",
      "name": "Sync-diff v1.0.0",
      "projectId": 11500,
      "releaseDate": "2022-02-16",
      "released": true,
      "self": "https://xxxxxxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/version/29704",
      "startDate": "2022-02-06",
      "userReleaseDate": "15/Feb/22",
      "userStartDate": "05/Feb/22"
    }
  ]
}
```

I just want to return any userReleaseDate that ends with '22'

I can get the boolean result by:

```
jq '.versions[].userReleaseDate | endswith("22")'
```

prints out false, false, true

But I am not sure how to retrieve the objects. I tried variations of this:

```
[.versions[] as $keys |  $keys select(endswith("22"))]
```

and each threw an error. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was so close:

```sh
jq '.versions[].userReleaseDate | endswith("22")'
```

Rather than *outputting* whether they end with `22` or not, you want to *select* the values which end with `22`. Fixed:

```sh
jq '.versions[].userReleaseDate | select( endswith("22") )'
```

Now, your question asks for the dates that end with `22`, but the title suggests you want the objects. For that, you'd want something a little different. We want to select from the versions, not from the dates.

```sh
jq '.versions[] | select( .userReleaseDate | endswith("22") )'       # As a stream
```

```sh
jq '[ .versions[] | select( .userReleaseDate | endswith("22") ) ]'   # As an array
```

```sh
jq '.versions | map( select( .userReleaseDate | endswith("22") ) )'  # As an array
```

---

There are a number of issues with `[ .versions[] as $keys | $keys select(endswith("22")) ]`.

- The keys of array element aren't usually called *keys* but *indexes*. `$indexes` would be a better name.
- Except `.versions[]` gets the *values* of the array elements, not the *keys*/*indexes*. `$values` would be a better name.
- Except the variable only takes on a single value at a time. `$value` would be a better name.
- `$version` would be an even better name.
- There's a `|` missing between `$keys` and `select(endswith("22"))`.
- There's no mention of `userReleaseDate` anywhere.
- The result is placed in an array (because of the `[ ]`). There's no need or desire for this.

You could use

```
.versions[] as $version | $version.userReleaseDate | select(endswith("22"))
```

or

```
.versions[].userReleaseDate as $date | $date | select(endswith("22"))
```

But these are just overly-complicated versions of

```sh
jq '.versions[].userReleaseDate | select( endswith("22") )'
```

Comment: Not the original poster, but I just want to say this is an extremely helpful reply that allowed me to parse my data in the way I wanted and also taught me some things about the structure of the data that I hadn't thought about. Thank you for the thorough explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Use `select` directly on the list of objects, extract and check the release date inside its argument:

```
jq '.versions[] | select(.userReleaseDate | endswith("22"))'
```

Comment: Or with just one pipe: `.versions[].userReleaseDate | select(endswith("22"))`

Comment: @pmf: It lists only the dates, not the objects.

Comment: OP said "I just want to return any userReleaseDate".

Comment: Re "*Or with just one pipe*", That makes it sound like they're equivalent, but they're not. The code in the answer outputs the entire object, and the code in the comment outputs just the date.  (The OP asked for the later.)

Comment: Well, the OP kind of asked for the objects, too: "I am not sure how to retrieve the objects", and also in the title.